# c++11 forwarddeclare thread,mutex,chrono

Tags: c++11, stl, forward-declaration

I am aware that we should prefer to forward declare everything in header files, if possible but what about STL?

I have found that for **iostream** there is **iosfwd**.

What if i want to have a **mutex** declared in my class, like this:

```
class MyClass
{

.....
private:
    std::mutex mMutex;
};
```

Should I include mutex header in my class header?
Or is there way to forwarddeclare it, like:

```
class std::mutex;
class MyClass{...};
```

Same goes for **chrono**, and **thread** as well.

Any thoughts on that is appreacited. Thanks!

Comment: You need the full definition of `std::mutex` for this anyway. The compiler must know the size of `mMutex` to figure out the size of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no portable way to forward declare std::objects, except as specified (e.g. `<iosfwd>`).  And there are no forwarding headers for `mutex`, `thread` or `chrono`.

Answer (score -1):

The C++ 11 standard states that forward declaring classes that are part of the **std** namespace cannot be forward declared (section 17.6.4.2.1):

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or
>   definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std
>   unless otherwise specified.

However for some reason the following piece of code does compile and run.

.h:

```
#pragma once

// Forward declaration of thread class that is part of the std namespace
namespace std
{
    class thread;
}

// Example declaration of a class using the forward declared class
class ExampleClass
{
    private:
        std::thread * _thread;
        void ThreadFunction(){}
}
```

.cpp

```
#include "ExampleClass.h"
#include <thread>

ExampleClass::ExampleClass() :
    _thread(new std::thread(std::bind(&ExampleClass::ThreadFunction, this)))
{

}
```

I compiled the code using visual studio 2015, perhaps that the C++ 11 standard statement no longer applies to C++14/17/20?

Comment: As you noted the statement from the standard says the behaviour is "undefined". One possible, conforming thing an implementation could do is allow your example to work. That doesn't indicate a change in the standard though.