# Is there a way to forward declare std::thread?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, std

I'm trying to avoid header file bloat, and in several of my classes I need a pointer to a `std::thread`. I've been forward declaring it like this: `namespace std { class thread; }`.
After turning on stricter warnings, the compiler tells me this is not defined behavior, but the code compiles and runs nonetheless (MSVC 2019).
I found this answer [c++11 forwarddeclare thread,mutex,chrono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642604/c11-forwarddeclare-thread-mutex-chrono), but it is from almost 7 years ago. Is there anything new in the standard that would allow me to do this in a proper way?

Comment: Howards answer is still current today.

Comment: *Is there anything new in the standard that would allow me to do this in a proper way?* Nope.

Comment: *"several of my classes I need a pointer to a `std::thread`"* - Why is that? I'm asking cause I often find `std::thread` is more convenient when held by value.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I have some threads that are only conditionally started, depending on configuration (read at runtime from file).

Comment: So? A default constructed `std::thread` doesn't execute anything. You can always have it run something later.

Comment: I missed the reason. Why?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I also don't want all other files including these headers to include `<thread>`, as they don't need it

Comment: I'm thinking you are barking up the wrong tree for that. PIMPL it away, and you won't have to mess with standard library preconditions and guarantees.